# I am trying to implement qsort algortihm as a generic function in C

Tags: c, generics, quicksort

My function returns a sorted array, but it's not the right one: some elements are duplicated and some others are deleted.
For example the expected return value for:
`[93,13,73,30,79,31,95,22,26,1]`
is:
`[1,13,22,26,30,31,73,79,93,95]`
I get this instead:
`[1,1,22,26,26,26,30,30,95,95]`

edit: thanks for your answers, I've corrected the errors you showed me in my code.
But it still doesn't work. I've completed my help request with my test functions
and I've changed the names of my variables to make them easier to understand.

this is my code :

My generic qsort implementation

Partition function, width : size of a value in bytes (1 byte = 8 bit)
void*T : the base
left : left index, right : right index                   compareFunction : function for sort order

```
int partition_g(size_t width, void *T, int left, int right,
               int (*compareFunction)(const void *, const void *)) {

    uint8_t *Tbyte = T;
    //uniform draw in set [d,...,f]
    uint32_t swap_index = (rand() % (right - left + 1)) + left;

    //We swap T[right] and T[swap_index]

    uint8_t *y = malloc(width);
    if(y==NULL)exit(-1);
    // y <-- T[swap_index]
    memcpy(y, (Tbyte + swap_index * width), width);
    // T[swap_index] <-- T[left]
    memcpy((Tbyte + swap_index * width), (Tbyte + right * width), width);
    // T[left] <-- T[swap_index]
    memcpy((Tbyte + right * width), (Tbyte + swap_index * width), width);

    uint8_t *x = malloc(width);
    if(x==NULL)exit(-1);
    // x <-- T[right]
    memcpy(x,Tbyte + right * width, width);

    int n = right;
    for (int i = right - 1; i >= left; i--) {
        //compare (T[i],x)
        if (compareFunction((Tbyte + i * width), x)>0)
        {
            //T[n] <-- T[i]
            memcpy((Tbyte + n * width), (Tbyte + i * width), width);
            //T[i] <-- T[n-1]
            memcpy((Tbyte + i * width), (Tbyte + (n-1) * width), width);
            n--;
        }
    }
    //T[n] <-- x
    memcpy((Tbyte + n * width), x, width);

    //free of allocate variable
    free(y);
    free(x);

    return n;
}
```

function that recursively calls the partion function

```
void recqsortg(void *array, size_t elementSize, 
                int (*compareFunction)(const void *, const void *),int left, int right) {
    if (right > left) {
        int n = partition_g(elementSize, array, left, right, compareFunction);

        recqsortg(array, elementSize, compareFunction, left, n - 1);
        recqsortg(array, elementSize, compareFunction, n + 1, right);
    }
}
```

main function

```
void qsortg(void *array, size_t elementCount, size_t elementSize,
            int (*compareFunction)(const void *, const void *)) {
    recqsortg(array, elementSize, compareFunction, 0, elementCount - 1);
}
```

function made for my testing function :

```
int a_strictSup_b_uint32(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return (*(uint32_t*)a > *(uint32_t*)b);
}

//function to display an array of integers
void printTab_entier_g(size_t nbelem, size_t width, void * T){
    uint64_t indice_depart;
    uint64_t res;
    uint8_t un_octet;
    uint8_t * Toctet = T;

    printf("[");

    for (int i = 0; i<nbelem; i++){
        res = 0;
        indice_depart = i * width;

        // on définit la valeur de res en parcourant width octets à partir de l'indice i
        for(int j = 0; j<width; j++){
            un_octet = *(Toctet + indice_depart + j);
            res = res + ((uint64_t)un_octet << j*8);
        }
        printf("%lu",res);
        if(i<nbelem-1)printf(",");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

//function for assigning an element to an array
void affectationg_tab_g(void* T, uint32_t indice, uint64_t number, size_t width){
    
    uint8_t * Tprime = T;
    uint64_t depart_affectation = width * indice;
    
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < width; i++){    //Attention l'entier number est tronqué si il > width
        *(Tprime + depart_affectation + i) = (number >> i*8) & 0xFF;
    }

}

//function that initializes an array of random elements in the set [0,...,99].
void init_random_tab_g(size_t Tlen, size_t width, void * T){
    uint32_t rd_number;
    for(int i = 0; i<Tlen; i++){
        rd_number = rand()%100;
        affectationg_tab_g(T,i,rd_number,width);
    }
}
```

//my test function

```
void test6()
{
    size_t Tlen = 10;
    uint32_t * T = malloc(Tlen*sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t * T2 = malloc(Tlen*sizeof(uint32_t));
    init_random_tab_g(Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),T);
    memcpy(T2,T,Tlen*sizeof(uint32_t));

    printf("input array :\n");
    printTab_entier_g(Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),T);

    qsortg(T,Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),a_strictSup_b_uint32);
    qsort(T2,Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),a_strictSup_b_uint32);
    printf("sorted by (my qsort)qsortg :\n");
    printTab_entier_g(Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),T);
    printf("Sorted by qsort :\n");
    printTab_entier_g(Tlen,sizeof(uint32_t),T2);


    free(T);
    free(T2);
}
int main(){
    //the way I initialize random
    srand(/*time(NULL)*/123);
    //how I call test6
    test6();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of all this code is :

input array :
[93,13,73,30,79,31,95,22,26,1]

sorted by (my qsort)qsortg :
[1,1,22,26,26,26,30,30,95,95]

Sorted by qsort :
[1,13,22,26,30,31,73,79,93,95]

Where we can see that my qsortg function is false

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `rand()%(d-f-1))+d` is wrong.

Comment: Why does your partition function need both `x` and `y`? You copy the same data into both of them, and do not afterward modify their contents until you free them.  They seem completely redundant.

Comment: I urge you to use more meaningful names for your variables. Among other things, doing so will help you more easily spot issues by making the intent of your code easier to understand.

Comment: You seem to be treating `compareFunction()` as boolean. The `qsort` uses its return value in the same way as `strcmp()` and `memcmp()`.

Comment: @eric And the rand() argument is wrong because the parameter names are chosen badly. Left/right or first/last and that mistake wouldn’t have happened.

Comment: Yes, thanks i've corrected it ```rand()%(d-f-1))+d``` it's now : ```rand()%(f-d+1)+d```

Comment: I don't need both Jhon, I was trying to make the code clearer. If it bothers you I can remove it.

Comment: Thanks  Weather Vane, I think it's correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show the comparison function you are using in your tests, and the question does not document the comparison function's expected behavior.  The usual convention for such functions is that of the standard library's `qsort()` function, which expects the comparison function's return value to be less than 0, equal to zero, or greater than zero according to whether the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

If that is your expectation too, then your `partitiong()` function uses the comparison function incorrectly.  With a conventional comparison function, this ...

> ```
>         if (compareFunction((Toctet + i * width), x))
> ```

... asks whether element `i` is unequal to the pivot value, but what you actually want to ask is whether it is *greater than* the pivot value.  That would be:

```
        if (compareFunction((Toctet + i * width), x) > 0)
```

Additionally, your formula for random pivot selection is questionable.  Consider:

> ```
>     uint32_t indice_swap = (rand() % (d - f - 1)) + d;
> ```

`d` is the index of the lower bound of the sub-array and `f` is the index of the upper bound.  You should expect, then, that `d - f - 1` will be negative.  In C, the `%` operator returns the algebraic quotient of its operands, with any fractional part truncated.  Among other things, that means that the result is negative when the operands are of opposite signs, and this will usually be the case for you because the return value of `rand()` is non-negative.  As a result, you are choosing pivots that are outside the sub-arrays you are trying to sort, and possibly outside the input array altogether.  You want this, instead:

```
    uint32_t indice_swap = (rand() % (f - d + 1)) + d;
```

---

*Added:*

Furthermore, you incorrectly implement the swap of the rightmost element with the pivot element.  Consider:

> ```
>     // T[swap_index] <-- T[left]
>     memcpy((Tbyte + swap_index * width), (Tbyte + right * width), width);
>     // T[left] <-- T[swap_index]
>     memcpy((Tbyte + right * width), (Tbyte + swap_index * width), width);
> ```

The code comments mix up 'left' and 'right', but even so, they give the correct idea about what is happening.  The pivot value is overwritten, and then and then that same value is copied back to the original location for no net effect.  It appears that you intended the latter to be

```
    // T[right] <-- y
    memcpy((Tbyte + right * width), y, width);
```

In practice, the only reason you need that last copy is because you later read `x` from the result.  If you instead read `x` from `y`, or if you just got rid of `x` and used `y` instead, then that would not be a problem.  This is why I overlooked that issue in the initial version of this answer.

---

With those <s>two</s> three changes, I was able to use a conventional-style comparison function with your code to get a correct sort of your example input array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Your answer is very complete and clear. I've corrected my code according to what you told me. But it still doesn't work properly. Can you please help me?  
(I've completed my request by adding my tests.)

Comment: @AlexandraTurner, I have updated this answer to address an additional issue in your code.

Comment: It's finally working, it's the first time I've had such a big bug, and I realize that it's just a stupid one. Thank you very much for your help, for the clarity of your answers and for your patience. Have a nice day/week-end or anything like that. Ty a lot